# Need a regex :(

Tags: python, regex

I'm using Python and I need to be able to take a string of the form

```
abc | pqr | [1,2,3,4,5]
```

and get the actual array of integers [1,2,3,4,5] from it. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would suggest trying some things in the interactive REPL. What have you tried? Why does it not work or what do you not like about it? I would likely start with a split on "one or more not digits" and then feed that through a map which takes the split parts (strings) and turns them into numbers. But, you could... try some things. (The approach above may be over-accepting.)

Comment: @Enrique Because now he has *two* problems... ;)

Comment: @Enrique: because *drum roll* ... he now has 2 problems! *rimshot*

Comment: @Ahmad Oops, sorry for stealing your show. ;-D

Comment: @deceze & @Ahmad: Sorry guys, i'm not getting the joke here, could you enlighten me? :)

Comment: @sthg http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247

Comment: Should be `Need a regex :D :D!!!!!!!!`.  Regex is fun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `abc | pqr |` part is literal characters, you want:

```
import re
import ast

m = re.match(r"abc \| pqr \| (\[[-0-9,]*\])", inString)
if m is not None:
    theList = ast.literal_eval(m.group(1))
```

Use `search` instead of `match` if you want to skip over leading non-matching characters.

Comment: Am trying this out - my lack of knowledge about ast's existence was the thing that was really killing me.

Comment: Bingo - thanks! Also, for informational purposes - what does the 'r' right inside the 'match' do?

Comment: That means "raw string", which handles backslash escapes differently.  Basically, backslashes are left in the string and not interpreted to mean other things by Python, so they're intact when `re` gets to see them.  So, for example, `r"\|"` is two characters (backslash and vertical bar).  Raw strings are commonly used with regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex will match the array of numbers, probably not perfect but that's my stab. Then you should be able to reference it with `$1`, not too familiar with pythons matcher though.

```
(\[.*\])
```

Comment: The above would get the string, then to get the ints in a list you could do something like `[int(x) for x in s.split(',')]`

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
import ast

s = "abc | pqr | [1,2,3,4,5]"

r = re.compile('\| (\[.*\])')
m = r.search(s)
if m:
  print ast.literal_eval(m.group(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variant without using literal_eval.

```
import re

matched = re.search(r'\[([0-9,]+)\]', "abc | pqr | [1,2,3,4,5]")
if matched:
  print map(int, matched.group(1).split(','))
  # or if your into list comprehensions
  print [int(i) for i in matched.group(1).split(',')]
```

Comment: I mis-typed.  I mean literal_eval.  I've corrected the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

The regex `\[([^\]]+)\]` will match the numbers inside the braces. Then split the result:

```
import re
str="abc | pqr | [1,2,3,4,5]"
reg=re.compile('\[([^\]]+)\]')
match=reg.search(s)
list=match.group(1).split()
```

list=['1,2,3,4,5']